# Converting phone Numbers into US type phone Number also for extension numbers using regExp

Tags: php, regex

I tried to convert phone numbers into us type phone numbers in PHP

Which is working fine by using another method but I want to work with regExp 
beginner in RegExp so confused with some code I tried
giving php code for better understanding

example
1 (800) 205 – 1111   ->   +1-800-205-1111

+341932831111        ->   +34-193-283-1111

01932831111          ->   +0-193-283-1111

+12 21 2501 1111     ->   +12-212-501-1111

21111                ->   +2-1111

`// Strip all non-numeric characters
    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
 //Calculating the length of the phone number
    $phoneNumberLength = strlen($phone);`

`// Using switch condition by phone number length 
    switch( $phoneNumberLength )  {
        case $phoneNumberLength <= 7:
            $phone = prepare_phone_number(substr($phone, 0, 1), substr($phone, 1, 4), NULL, NULL);
            break;
        case 10:
            // If we have 10 digits and 1 not the first, add 1
            $phone =  '1' . $phone;
            $phone = prepare_phone_number(substr($phone, 0, 1), substr($phone, 1, 3), substr($phone, 4, 3), substr($phone, 7, 4));
            break;
        case 11:
            $phone = prepare_phone_number(substr($phone, 0, 1), substr($phone, 1, 3), substr($phone, 4, 3), substr($phone, 7, 4));
            break;
        default:
            $phone = prepare_phone_number(substr($phone, 0, 2 ), substr($phone, 2, 3 ), substr($phone, 5,3), substr($phone, 8,4));
    }
    return $phone;
}`
`// Created new function to concat phone number in proper US format
function prepare_phone_number($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4)
{
    return  implode( '-', array_filter( [ '+' . $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4 ] ) );
}`

Comment: So you want to replace ALL THAT PARSING CODE with a simple RegEx? Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer to your question, also be sure there are alot of ways to do anything using regular expressions, so i don't say my answer is best, but i think it can do what do you want:-

- Firstly reverse the phone number string which you deleted all non-numeric characters.
- After that find captured parts of the number using below regex pattern.
- And finally join the captured numbers however you want.

> The string reversing function

`strrev(str)`

> The regular expression pattern

`/(1{4})(\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d{1,3})/`

**The Code to do what i described:-**

```
$phone = '01932831111'

/*reverse phone number*/
$phone = strrev($phone);

/*replace with (-) and (+) which do you want*/
$reg_result = preg_replace('/(1{4})(\\d{3})?(\\d{3})?(\\d{1,3})/', '$1-$2-$3-$4+', $phone);

/*if there was two captured boxes*/
$res_2 = str_replace('--', '-', $reg_result);

/*if there was three captured boxes*/
$res_1 = str_replace('---', '-', $reg_result);

/*finally reverse the string to get the result*/
$result = strrev($res_1);

echo $result;
```

**The Result**

```
+0-193-283-1111
```

Comment: One correction only other solution is working all fine for me

`$reg_result = preg_replace('\\d{3})(\\d{3})?(\\d{3})?(\\d{1,3})/', '$1-$2-$3-$4+', $phone);`
Thanks for helping me out